# How can I find all solutions of this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve this equation with integer solution
$x^3 + (x + 1)^3 + (x + 2)^3 + (x + 3)^3 + (x + 4)^3 + (x + 
     5)^3 + (x + 6)^3 + (x + 7)^3 = y^3.$
I tried

```
Solve[{x^3 + (x + 1)^3 + (x + 2)^3 + (x + 3)^3 + (x + 4)^3 + (x + 
   5)^3 + (x + 6)^3 + (x + 7)^3 == y^3}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

and got massage

```
{{y -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-784 - 420 x - 84 x^2 - 8 x^3 + #1^3 &, 
     1], (x | 
       Root[-784 - 420 x - 84 x^2 - 8 x^3 + #1^3 &, 1]) \[Element] 
 Integers]}}
```

If I tried

```
Solve[{x^3 + (x + 1)^3 + (x + 2)^3 + (x + 3)^3 + (x + 4)^3 + (x + 
   5)^3 + (x + 6)^3 + (x + 7)^3 == y^3, -1000 <= x <= 2000}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

I got

```
{{x -> -5, y -> -6}, {x -> -4, y -> -4}, {x -> -3, y -> 4}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> 6}}
```

It seems all solutions of the given equation.
How can I find all solutions of the given equation?

Comment: On version 12.2.0 the command `Solve[{x^3 + (x+1)^3 + (x+2)^3 + (x+3)^3 + (x+4)^3 + (x+5)^3 + (x+6)^3 + (x+7)^3 == y^3}, {x, y}, Integers]` gives all solutions: `{{x->-5, y->-6}, {x->-4, y->-4}, {x->-3, y->4}, {x->-2, y->6}}`.

Comment: Or `Reduce[{x^3 + (x + 1)^3 + (x + 2)^3 + (x + 3)^3 + (x + 4)^3 + (x + 
       5)^3 + (x + 6)^3 + (x + 7)^3 == y^3}, {x, y}, Integers]`

Comment: Or `FindInstance[{x^3 + (x + 1)^3 + (x + 2)^3 + (x + 3)^3 + (x + 
       4)^3 + (x + 5)^3 + (x + 6)^3 + (x + 7)^3 == y^3}, {x, 
  y}, Integers, 10]` which results in `{{x -> -5, y -> -6}, {x -> -4, y -> -4}, {x -> -3, y -> 4}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> 6}}` in 12.2.

Comment: One way would be to show that there can be no solutions outside of certain bounds, and then check within those bounds exhaustively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation for the sum of 8 consecutive cubes becomes $y^3=u^3+63u$ on substitution of $x=(u-7)/2$.

```
y^3 == Simplify[784 + 420 x + 84 x^2 + 8 x^3 /. x -> (u - 7)/2]
```

> y^3 == u (63 + u^2)

The substitution is equivalent to $u=2x+7$, implying $u$ must be odd.

$y<$0 requires $u<0$ because $63+u^2$ is always positive. $y>0$ requires odd $u>0$.

Rewrite the equation as the difference of two cubes $y^3-u^3=63u$, and expand on the comment by @DanielLichtblau.

For $y>0$, the minimum difference between two positive cubes occurs when $y=u+1$. This minimum difference is $1+3u+3u^2$. As positive odd $u$ increases, the minimum difference will eventually exceed $63u$ for some $u$.

```
Reduce[{1 + 3 u + 3 u^2 > 63 u, u > 0}, u, Integers]
```

> u [Element] Integers && u >= 20

Therefore, the only possible odd positive $u$ are $1\le u\le 19$. Similarly for negative odd $u$ with $-19\le u \le -1$.

A simple search of these 20 candidates gives all 4 solutions.

```
{x, y} -> Select[
    Table[{(u - 7)/2, 
            CubeRoot[784 + 420 x + 84 x^2 + 8 x^3 /. x -> (u - 7)/2]},
          {u, -19, 19, 2}],
    IntegerQ[#[[2]]] &]
```

> {x, y} -> {{-5, -6}, {-4, -4}, {-3, 4}, {-2, 6}}